# how to set parameter in ssrs which shows timeframe

Tags: jquery, ssrs-2012

> I have created ssrs report which has a parameter for start date. I
>   want another parameter which shows time-frame of 6months,12 months,18
>   months,24 months which calculate dynamically from my start date.

**my query**

```
select distinct [dbo].[MSP_EpmResource_UserView].[ResourceName], [dbo].[MSP_EpmProject_UserView].[ProjectUID],[dbo].[MSP_EpmProject_UserView].[ProjectManagerName] , 
       [dbo].[MSP_EpmTask_UserView].[TaskStartDate],[dbo].[MSP_EpmTask_UserView].[TaskFinishDate],
       [dbo].[MSP_EpmTask_UserView].[TaskPercentCompleted],[dbo].[MSP_EpmProject_UserView].[Project Status] AS StatusForExecutiveReporting,
       [dbo].[MSP_EpmProject_UserView].[ProjectSubject] AS NotesForExecutiveReport 
from  dbo.MSP_EpmAssignment_UserView 
INNER JOIN dbo.MSP_EpmProject_UserView
ON dbo.MSP_EpmAssignment_UserView.ProjectUID = dbo.MSP_EpmProject_UserView.ProjectUID     
INNER JOIN dbo.MSP_EpmTask_UserView 
ON dbo.MSP_EpmAssignment_UserView.TaskUID = dbo.MSP_EpmTask_UserView.TaskUID    
inner join   [dbo].[MSP_EpmResource_UserView]
on dbo.MSP_EpmAssignment_UserView.ResourceUID = dbo.MSP_EpmResource_UserView.ResourceUID  
where   [dbo].[MSP_EpmTask_UserView].[TaskStartDate] = @Startdate
order by  [dbo].[MSP_EpmResource_UserView].[ResourceName]
```

Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a drop down that shows the actual calculated dates instead of displaying text like **12 months**, you'll need to add a separate dataset for it. Then use this data set for your End Date parameter's **Available Values** query.

It doesn't matter what it connects to since it won't be using a table - you just need SQL server (or whatever db) to run the query to calculate the dates.

```
SELECT DATEADD("M",  6, @StartDate) as EndDate 
UNION
SELECT DATEADD("M", 12, @StartDate) 
UNION
SELECT DATEADD("M", 18, @StartDate) 
UNION
SELECT DATEADD("M", 24, @StartDate)
```